# Sorting list of tuples by multiple keys that can be empty

Tags: python, sorting

I try to sort list of tuples first by 1st element, than by 2nd (if it exists), than by 3rd (if it exists).

Since the tuples are of different length, some of them does not have 2nd or/and 3rd element, so the error appears: `IndexError: list index out of range on line undefined.`

```
list_to_sort = [(1, 11), (2, 0, 0), (1, 2), (2), (0, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

expected output:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 11), (2), (2, 0), (2, 0, 0)]
```

What I tried to do already, but the same error appears: `IndexError: list index out of range on line undefined.`

1.

```
print(sorted(list_to_sort,key=lambda  x:(x[0], x[1], x[2])))
```

2. 

```
print(sorted(list_to_sort,key=lambda  x:(x[0],(x[1] is not None, x[1]), (x[2] is not None, x[2])))
```

3. 

```
def check(x):
  if x:
    return x
  else:
    return ""

print(sorted(list_to_sort,key=lambda  x:(x[0], check(x[1]), check(x[2])))
```

I want the code to check if the 2nd/3rd element is there and if yes sort with it's value, if not - suppose that it is empty or zero for sorting purposes.

It seems easy, but I'm running out of options here. Any suggestions are welcome :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are describing is the normal comparison behavior of tuples.  Just sort the list, no `key=` function needed.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the core issue here is that `(2)` is not a tuple right?  Otherwise if you make it one `print(sorted(list_to_sort))` give you the correct result right?

Comment: The error you probably were getting while trying simple comparisons is because your list doesn't contain only tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the basic, default sorting for a list a tuples however one of the items in your list might look like a tuple `(2)` but is an `int`. For it to be a tuple it would look more like `(2,)`.

If that item was a tuple then you could just do:

```py
print(sorted(list_to_sort))
```

So, that gives us a clue as to how to proceed. Let's assume for a moment that you want that item to be an `int` but would like to sort it as if it was a tuple. We can try:

```py
print(sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda x: x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,)))
```

That will give you:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 11), 2, (2, 0), (2, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is a valid point, I did not notice that before!